# trying to execute a selector with electron

Tags: electron

when executting this code, nothing shows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <base href="./">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<body>
   <app-administrador>Administrador...</app-administrador> 
</body>
</html>
```

Im using angular electron, just like any angular

```
my Component({
  selector: 'app-administrador',
  templateUrl: './administrador.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./administrador.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `Electron`?

Comment: Im doing that in Electron Angular

Comment: As your question is, it is hard to answer. I would do the following steps to debug: Do you see any errors in the browser console (chrome dev tools)? A white window is often caused by an error while loading the site - so open the devtools of the electron window and look if anything shows up on the console. Does your code work in a normal browser with regular angular? If you build your app with regular angular and then open it in an electron window - does it behave differently?

Comment: I found the problem, but dont know how to solve it. indexAdministrador.html never goes to dist directory. ANy hint, could be my package.json.Help is welcom